# general struct in c for reading (almost) an arbitrary txt dataline

Tags: c

I want to read in a numerical data line from a text file. The line has two parts:
The first part is an index and could be one integer, two integers, ...or no integers at all!
The second part could be one or two numbers of type integer, double, or float.

From the file's header I know what to expect BUT how can I read these lines generally in C without if/casing dozens of cases?? I've thought of unions, X-macros, enums...etc. To add to the problem, I can't point to datatypes in C because I was thinking once I can identify my case I can point to an appropriate datatype. At least I can point to a function.

the goal is to simply load the data into memory. i wanted to use structs but no i think i'm just going to have pointers to each part.

Am I asking too much of C??

Comment: Are you saying that once the header is read, every line has the same format, or can every line still be different?  What do you need to do with the data?  How do you intend to process it?

Comment: " Am I asking too much of C?? " , entire operating systems, frameworks and compilers were constructed in c , am sure C can handle your little file parsing program , so get started !!

Comment: If you need to make a decision, you need to make a decision, and that's where you use `if` and `switch`. You may benefit from implementing an explicit finite state machine to read and parse your lines with numbers and whatever else information is in them. Draw all possible cases, states and state transitions and then code the FSM straight from the diagram.

Comment: Can you include in your question some short examples of the data files that you have to process? In particular, is there some characteristic that distinguishes the first part of the line from the second part (otherwise it might be hard to tell the difference between a single index integer in the first part and a second part that contains an integer but which follows a "no index" first part). Distinguishing a double from a float in a text file would be impossible for most cases without additional hints in the file and may be unnecessary in practice.

Comment: @all the lines are all the same so i will only make a decision once as i read the metadata.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze i'm not that deep in CS but i was thinking along the lines of using combinations and set theory to identify my cases.

Answer (score 1):

You really just have lines containing from 1 to 4 numbers.  So:

```
char line[LINE_MAX]; // populate this somehow
double values[4];
int count = sscanf(line, "%f %f %f %f", &values[0], &values[1], &values[2], &values[3]);
// now count tells you how many values were read, so ignore the others
```

You might say, "but I wanted integer support too!"  Well, you got it.  And you got it without any "if" statements.  So be happy, and know that a bunch of programming languages (e.g. Javascript, Lua) don't really worry about this distinction either.

Comment: yes i want the appropriate datatype stored in memory.

Comment: node.value[0]=value[0],... node=node.next ... or you can do a linked list of linked lists or a 2 dimensional array or... it depends on how you are going to use it

Comment: @majidaldosari: well, surely between float and double you'll have a hard time deciding which is more "appropriate."  And between int and double it probably doesn't really matter either.  I encourage you to try my suggestion and come back if it presents a specific problem that we can solve.  Or, hey, you can use unions, ugliness and all.

Answer (score 0):

i think i'm going to generate functions that all take the same array of pointers.

I'm going to manually write functions that process 0, 1 or 2 indexes but generate the datatypes with macros like

```
int readingfunc1(aline,arrofp){

return sscanf(aline,"%d XSTRFORMATDATATYPESLIST XSTRFORMATDATATYPESLIST", arrofp[2],arrofp[3])
//arrofp={arrofp[0], NULL, arrofp[2],arrofp[3]}
```

func0 and func2 as appropriate.